# MongoDB date import via Talend from Oracle is out by 1 day

Tags: oracle, mongodb, talend, isodate

I am actually using the mongDB API via a tLibraryLoad component, as I find this easier to build complex multi-level documents using tJavaRow and tJava components, than using the MongoDB palette components.

I am reading in data from Oracle which are date values with a zero time stamp component:  For example:

> 29-JUN-08 00.00.00

The import works via Talend, however the records in mongo shell appear to be the previous day.  You can see the record is inserted as the 28-JUN-2008.

Extract from JSON document in mongoDB:

> "status_date" : ISODate("2008-06-28T23:00:00Z")

It is almost as if mongoDB (or Talend?) sees a midnight date as the end of the previous day, rather than the start of the 29th June 2008.

In my Talend schema I have specified the Oracle columns as Date types with a DB Type of Date also.

Any advice appreciated.

---UPDATE 1------
As only some dates are affected, it seems this is a DST adjustment in mongoDB to adjust perhaps the display to my local timezone, as the dates which are impacted are in the back half of the year in daylight saving time.

Is it  adjusting the date due to the location of the mongo shell?

It is adjusting the date due to the location of the mongo server so all people using the mongo shell would get the same answers to date queries?

Would different people running different mongo queries on dates get different results based on their location, their DST kick in dates...i.e. you could imagine dates from the 1st November 2015, being counted as contributing to October 31st figures (at 23:00)....

i

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain - this is derived from MongoDB itself.

At issue is that MongoDB stores dates in UTC format by default.

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-time-data/

You can use Mongo's suggestion above but in this case you are storing just the date and not the time. I've used two solutions:

1. Don't bother storing dates as DATEs. Convert all your dates to %Y%m%d format and store them as integers. You can easily compare dates using $gt and $lte just using integers - just be sure to bring in your date using the same format and convert them back in your program later.

... or ...

2. Since in your case your date seems to be off by an hour, add an hour to it before you make your insert. It all depends on how long the timezone offset is to your local machine.

On linux you can see what the utc value is using:

```
date -u
```

I suppose you could change your local timezone on your machine to be UTC time and see what happens.

Personally, I've never had an issue with using the first approach. It's fast and ensures that I have what I want in there.

Comment: Hi, thanks.  where is the timezone kicking in?  Is it in Oracle?  My Talend job is running locally on my laptop which is UTC timezone UK (+00 hours)?  I need to do any date conversions using java libraries as I am using the tJavaRow component and the mongoDB java API.  In Oracle I am storing as date not timestamp with timezone.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of the timezone of your server. Try to remove the timezone from your date object and then insert it to the mongodb.

With moment.js you can create date without the timezone in such way:

```
var date = moment.utc("29-JUN-08 00.00.00", 'DD-MM-YYYY h.mm.s').format()
```

Comment: hi, my only option is to use the java api, not javascript within Talend I think.  I understand how the timezone of the server would adjust a sysdate call, but how would it impact the writing of a stored value being read from Oracle?